# Set Theory: Disprove if $B ∩ C ⊆ A$, then $(A − B) ∩ C = B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to disprove the set as stated in the title. Can this be solved by adding values to each set, such as $A = \{1\}$, $B=\{2, 3\}$, etc.? If so, can you give me a hint to get started?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How can left -B while right still have B?

Comment: To disprove it, you just need to produce a counterexample. An easy one is $A=B=C$ for any nonempty set $A$.

Comment: Got it, thank you!!

Comment: You don't need an example.  If $b \in B$ then $b \not \in A-B$ so $b\not \in (A-B)\cap C$.  So $B$ can't *possibly* be $(A-B)\cap C$ as every element of $B$ is *not* in $(A-B)\cap C$.  They have *no* elements in common!

Comment: @fleablood. Good point. So it's false for every non-empty $B$.... Also false if $B$ is empty and $A\cap C$ is not

Comment: $B$ and $B^c$ and $A-B$  and $(A-B)\cap C$ etc. are conceptually incompatible.  $B^c$ and $A-B$ and $(A-B)\cap C$ etc are all *defined* to completely *disjoint* from $B$.  I have to wonder, how did you come across this question.

Answer (score 2):

Just as mentioned in the comment, the idea is that LHS has no $B$, but RHS is $B$ exactly. Therefore, as long as $B$ is non-empty, the equality does not hold. For an explicit counterexample, let $A = C = \emptyset$, $B = \{1\}$. Then:

- $B \cap C = \emptyset \subseteq A$
- $(A - B) \cap C = \emptyset \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$
- $B = \{1\}$

Comment: Great, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

A proof using the membership table method : I use the symbol " V" ( vrai) for " true" and the symbol " F" ( faux) for false.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it is false then either there is a $b\in B$ that is not in $(A-B)\cap C$, or there is a $k \in (A-B)\cap C$ that is not in $B$.

1) Let's see if we can find a $b \in B$ that is not in $(A-B)\cap C$.

Well..... if $b \in B$ then $b$ is not in $A-B$ because $A-B$ is all the elements in $A$ that are *not* in $B$.  And so $b$ is not in $(A-B) \cap C$ because $(A-B) \cap C$ are all the elements that are in both $(A-B)$ and $C$.

So *any* example with any $B$ will do.

Let $B= \{2,3\}$ and $C=\{1,2\}$.  Then $B\cap C = \{2\} \subset A$ is or only requirement.  So let $A = \{1,2,3\}$.

Then $A-B = \{1\}$ and $(A-B)\cap C = \{1\}$ which has *no* elements of $B$.

Or more meaty

Let $B = \{2,4,6,8,10,12\}$ and $C=\{3,6,9,12\}$.  We need $B\cap C \subset A$ so $B\cap C = \{6,12\}$ let's just have $A=\{6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$.

Then $A-B = \{7,9,11\}$ and $(A-B)\cap C = \{7,9,11\}\cap \{3,6,9,12\}= \{9\}$ and that ... isn't $B$.

Are you *sure* you had the question right?  This can *never* be true.  $(A-B) \cap C$ will never have *ANY* elements in common with $B$ much less be *equal* to $B$.